# WSO2 Gadget Gen Tool -

Tags: hive, wso2, wso2-bam

I have an external Hadoop cluster (CDH4) with Hive.  I used the Gadget Gen tool (BAM 2.3.0) to create a simple table gadget, but no data is populated when I add the gadget to a dashboard using the URL supplied from the gadget gen tool.

Here's my data source settings from the Gadget Generator Wizard

> jdbc:hive://x.x.x.x:10000/default
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

I added the following jar files to make sure I had everything required for the JDBC connection and restarted wso2server:

> hive-exec-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar hive-jdbc-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar
>   hive-metastore-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar hive-service-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar
>   libfb303-0.9.0.jar commons-logging-1.0.4.jar slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
>   slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0.jar

I see map reduce jobs running on my cluster during step 2 and 3 of the wizard (and the wizard shows me previews of the actual data), but I don't see any jobs submitted after the gadget is generated.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Gadgen gen tool is for RDBMS database such as MySQL,h2, etc. you can't provide hive URL from the gadget gen tool and run it.

Generally in WSO2 BAM, the hive is used to summarize the collected data which was stored in  cassandra and write the summarized final result on RDBMS database. Then from Gadget-gen tool, the gdaget xmls are created by pointing to the final result stored RDBMS database.

You can find more information on WSO2 BAM 2.3.0 documentation. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Gadget+Generation+Tool

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the URL generated for the location of Gadget XML has the correct IP/Host Name. See whether the given gadget xml is located in the registry location of the generated url. You do not have to worry about Hive / Hadoop / Cassandra stuff as they are not relevant to the Gadget. Only the RDBMS (H2 by default) data matters. Hope your problem will be resolved when Gadget location is corrected.

Comment: Here's the URL from the generator wizard:
http: //172.19.0.171:9763/registry/resource/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.bam.gadgetgen/gadgetgen/test7june20130830.xml

Here's the jag file from inside the xml:
https://172.19.0.171:9443/gadgetgen/test7june20130830.jag

And here's the error when I visit the jag URL:
HTTP Status 500 - org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error connecting to the database : jdbc:hive://172.19.0.109:10000/default (/gadgetgen//test7june20130830.jag#4)

Comment: Other information about my system: Using Oracle JDK 1.7.0_21, RHEL 5.7 x86_64

Comment: Seems the jdbc handler details entered during gadget gen wizard has a problem.  Either you need to enter the Oracle jdbc driver correctly or jdbc driver should be added to repository/components/lib directory correctly. And also check the jdbc username and password again.

Comment: Everything was entered correctly, as it's displaying query results during the preview phases of the wizard.  All the jar files including hive-jdbc have been added to /root/wso2bam-2.3.0/repository/components/lib.  How can I examine the code of the gadget to make sure the generation tool transfered the connection parameters correct?  Could it be possible that the gadget gen wizard and gadget server aren't using the same lib location for the JDBC driver?

Comment: Is the Oracle JDBC driver needed for Hive?  I'm not using Oracle anywhere in my architecture.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake. I got wrong with Oracle JDK comment. If you are using the default H2 database packed with BAM enter as follows. JDBC URL : jdbc:h2:repository/database/samples/BAM_STATS_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
Driver Class Name : org.h2.Driver 
User Name : wso2carbon 
Password : wso2carbon